# copy conditional formatting format but not rules/numbers

Tags: vba, excel

need some help thinking through how to do this.

ultimately, what i want to achieve is to sum together cells based on if another corresponding cell is 0 or 1. it's a bit convoluted but i'll try my best to explain.

sheet 1 has data that shows, by month, if actuals have come in for the month. a column will display a 0 for accounts/month that need to be added.

sheet 2 has two tables. table 1 pulls in the 0 & 1 from sheet 1 and uses conditional formatting to highlight cells that need to be added. the only thing in this table is 0 & 1. table 2 is the exact same setup as table 1, just with the actual numbers.

my original thought was to just copy the highlighting format from table 1 onto table 2 then use a macro to sum highlighted cells. obviously, i have found that that is not possible.

i tried looking around and haven't found anything that lets me just copy the highlighting format without overwriting the numbers in table 2.

is this possible?

Comment: "my original thought was to just copy the highlighting format from table 1 onto table 2 then use a macro to sum highlighted cells. obviously, i have found that that is not possible." - What makes you say that? I think you could quickly have a UDF that looks for highlighted cells, then adds them all together.

Comment: @BruceWayne the cells that need to be added are in table 2 while the cells that are highlighted are in table 1. i dont think there is anyway for me to make table 2 itself have the formatting due to my formulas.

Comment: Usually, screenshots are discouraged (we prefer copy/pasted data), but I think it'd help if you could show some sample data/the two tables.  I kind of see what you're saying, but not completely.  Would you mind putting in a screenshot? (If you don't have enough rep. to post image, just upload one to [https://www.imgur.com](imgur) and post the link(s) in your OP.

Comment: @BruceWayne actually your post made me rethink the table split thing and i think i found a way to highlight table 2 based on table 1 with just an extra step. so now i just need to sum the highlighted cells!

Comment: No problemo - I already have a UDF for that. But let's tweak it - can you clarify: Do you want to sum **all** highlighted cells, or just ones a certain color? Also, what range do you have these cells in? Could they be anywhere in the page, or are they restricted to say columns A-D?

Comment: @BruceWayne
so table 1 has the months as columns per account. i want to go through each account (row) and sum of all highlighted (there's only one color) months (column). i found this, but it doesn't work in my worksheet. when i download it separately it works though. http://www.excelexchange.com/SumByColor.html

so for ABC account i would be summing feb, mar and for BBC all three months. accounts on y axis and months on x.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm not sure how your data is laid out, but if it's in a row, you can run this on a new cell at the end of that row (meaning, the next empty column):

```
Function sumHighlighted(ByVal myRng As Range)
Dim cel As Range, iRow As Range
Dim fSum As Long, totalRows As Long

fSum = 0

For Each cel In Range(Cells(myRng.Row, 1), Cells(myRng.Row, myRng.Column))
    If cel.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
        fSum = fSum + cel.Value
    End If
Next cel

Debug.Print "The total in this row is: " & fSum
sumHighlighted = fSum

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: i'm getting a #NAME error? same thing as the other function i tried to use.

Comment: also complete noob at vba so you might need to do some hand holding in terms of where and how to activate function.

Comment: @Rlee Place this in a workbook module, see [this page](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/) for how.  Once it's in there, you should be able to type the formula and get it working.

Comment: @RLee - What's not working? What are you doing, that's not working? Does it return an error still? Or does it just not sum properly?

Comment: oh, it works, no more #NAME. though the highlighting is from conditional formatting and the function does not seem to be picking that up? a regularly highlighted cell works but not the ones with conditional formatting?

Comment: @RLee - Ooooh - that's a good point. I'll have to look in to this.  Although, if we know that highlighted cells match some condition, can you use that condition in a `SumIf()` or `SumIfs()`??

Comment: ill give it a try. also, how do i change it so it sums a specific range instead of just the entire range to the left of the designated cell. forgot to mention losta tables in my file haha.

Comment: actually nvm, if there is a way to sum conditionally formatted cells please let me know!

Comment: @RLee - What's your conditional formatting formula?

Comment: basically if cell from table 1 = 0, highlight cell from table 2. i was able to figure something out that doesn't need a macro, but for future reference i wonder if you can actually sum conditional formatting. searched a bit and i think we cant?

Comment: @RLee - Hm, you [may be able to](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/conditional-formatting-tricks-sum-values-in-excel-by-cell-color/).

Answer (score 0):

Steps: 
1. Copy the Cell with conditional Format. 
2. Paste to cell where you want (Hold ALT + press E + S + T).

To generate a code, click "Record Macro" first and do the 2 steps above and stop the recording macro once you're done.